# Three.js + leaflet = 3D maps?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, 3d, three.js, leaflet

This may be a pretty hefty task, but I'm looking for something that can help me create 3D maps  with leaflet.  I already have leaflet up and running, I just want to transform them into 3D perspective.

My only purpose for this is to display buildings in 3D.  I have already used [OSM Buildings](http://osmbuildings.org/), however they are not real 3D.

I also found [ReadyMap](http://demo.pelicanmapping.com/rmweb/webgl/tests/leaflet.html), by Pelican Mapping, which supports Leaflet already, but I cannot get this API to work successfully because they haven't updated it in awhile.  I've already asked on their Github, so there isn't much coming from that road as of now unless I can figure out how to fix the ReadyMap issues (and their src is tens of thousands of lines).  I also have no clue whether OSM buildings would even work with ReadyMap.

So right now, I'm looking for any other options out there.  My 2 biggest prospects are

[Cesium AGI](http://cesium.agi.com/)

and

[Three.js](http://threejs.org/)

**I essentially want my end result to look something like this:**

Go [here](http://eagle.gmu.edu/map/fairfax.php), and click "Earth" on the right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find any suitable solutions, especially for 2.5D maps (not imagery)? Thanks

Comment: @knuthole Yes I did actually, though it wasn't quite as streamlined as I would have liked.  I ended up using several JS libraries, namely dat.gui, three.js, and leaflet. In leaflet I created a standard map and plugged in OSM buildings for structures, and atop this I created a UI panel with dat.gui to allow switching between "2.5D" and 3D interface.  For the 3D part, I had to manually download the map tiles, create a plane surface in three.js and apply the map images, and manually create some building shapes and apply textures to them

Comment: @knutole If you'd like to see some screenshots of how it turned out, let me know.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'd like to see the results!

Comment: @knutole 3D portion - http://i306.photobucket.com/albums/nn255/Krb686/cest_3d_1.png

Comment: @krb686 : is it possible to share a code example ?

Comment: I would also love to see some code examples.

Comment: Same, would love some code examples.

Comment: @krb686 How did you integrate the 3d view with the leaflet layer controls? I'm having a hard time getting my 3d buildings to pan and zoom along with the rest of the layers. One issue is actually getting the 3d layer to show up without also interfering with the leaflet pan/zoom. Any tips?

Comment: I haven't looked at this in awhile.  I just came back to it and unfortunately discovered that my tile provider for the maptiles no longer provides free access.  I'm going to try to replace the tile provider and point you guys to a working demo

Comment: @Spencer For the distinction between 2D and 3D, I actually used 2 div elements called `2dcontainer` and `3dcontainer` inside a div called `content`. and they both overlap.  One is hidden and the other is not.  Of course I have leaflet tied to the `2dcontainer` and three.js tied to the `3dcontainer`.  I then use dat.gui to create a control and allow switching between the 2 divs.  So truthfully, I wouldn't say I actually integrated full 3D with leaflet since when I switch to 3D mode, it's essentially just a three.js viewport that happens to use the exact same mapfiles for the base texture.

Comment: @Spencer However in "2D" mode, I use OSM buildings to provide some sort of dimension.

Answer (score 5):

You may take a look of [maptalks](https://github.com/maptalks/maptalks.js), a javascript library to create integrated 2D/3D maps.

(I'm the main author)

Comment: Hey, your username matches the main author of that project, if that is not a coincidence could you mention so. (Nice library though)

Comment: @jrtapsell Yeah, I'm the main author, pardon me if any disturb  : P

Comment: Great library! Super easy to create 3D lines (lat, lon, altitude) with simple leaflet background tiles: https://maptalks.org/examples/en/3d/line-draw-altitude/#3d_line-draw-altitude

Answer (score 5):

I and some colleges have created a 3D-Plugin for Leaflet during a University project.

You can check it out here:

https://mocainfo.thm.de/building-3d/
(Top left corner is the 3D-Button)

Its created with WebGL (Basically Three.js with less stuff around it). The link I wanted to share contains the important math used for Placing the 3D-Stuff:

http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/c6fed35c377a46ff74c3

The 3D-Models are generated from OSM-Data and/or are modeled in Blender. The Rendering is simple Flat-Shading Lighting. There are plenty of tutorials on that.

If there are any specific questions, just ask.

Answer (score 4):

There is something called F4 Map, but there is not much information about this project. Check [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/F4_Map) for some details.

Example of map: [Moscow](http://map.f4-group.com/#lat=55.7512343&lon=37.6169525&zoom=17&camera.theta=51.32&camera.phi=54.431)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check the [new version of OSMBuildings](https://github.com/OSMBuildings/OSMBuildings), which is real 3D.